# calcular fecha de entrega solo tomando en cuenta los dias laborables en javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var fechaIncio = new Date();
var fechaTotal = new Date();

var FechasFestivas = [
    [1],
    [40],
    [19, 25],
    [19, 22],
    [1],
    [24, 29],
    [40],
    [15],
    [40],
    [9, 12],
    [1],
    [6, 25],
];

fechaTotal.setDate(fechaTotal.getDate() + 10);
var diaSaDo = 0;
var diafestivo = 0;
var dom = 0;
var sab = 6;

while (fechaIncio.getDate() < fechaTotal.getDate()) {
    document.getElementById("a").prepend("dia inicio = " + fechaIncio.getDate() + "---");
    if (fechaIncio.getDay() == dom || fechaIncio.getDay() == sab) {
        diaSaDo++;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i <= FechasFestivas[fechaIncio.getMonth()].length; i++) {
            if (fechaIncio.getDate() == FechasFestivas[fechaIncio.getMonth()][i]) {
                diafestivo++;
            }
        }
    }
    fechaIncio.setDate(fechaIncio.getDate() + 1);
}

fechaIncio.setDate(fechaIncio.getDate() + diaSaDo + diafestivo);
```

Comment: Aparte del título..., podrías añadir: Que quieres hacer?, Cuál crees que es el error?, o comentar que hace cada parte del código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto te ayude, por lo menos así lo haría yo.

En primer lugar debemos establecer un par de cosas en tu pregunta, ya que voy a asumirlas de acuerdo al código que has publicado.

Lo primero es establecer que el `Array` de festivos contiene los días festivos. Sin embargo en tu ejemplo pones más de un par de veces el número 40, y que yo sepa, al menos en la Tierra, los meses tienen a lo sumo 31 días. Imagino que es un error de tipeo y así lo asumo. También asumo que el `Array` de días festivos contiene los días en formato `Number`, agrupados a su vez en arrays de acuerdo al número del mes.

<strike>Lo segundo que voy a asumir, ya que no aportas información al respecto, es que la fecha que recibes como fecha de inicio viene en algún formato válido, sea `String`, `Number` o `Date`.</strike>

*Leyendo bien tu comentario, veo que la fecha de pedido es la fecha actual, por lo tanto hago las modificaciones necesarias.*

Hechas esas dos acotaciones, vamos a lo que nos ocupa (usaré sintaxis de ES6 )

```js
// Array con los días festivos de cada mes (ejemplo de muestra)
// Nótese que si un mes no tiene festivos debemos incluir igualmente un array vacío, (ejemplo: Noviembre)
const festivos = [[1, 7, 8],[27, 28],[1],[6, 9],[1],[15],[9],[17, 18, 19],[10],[12, 23],[],[25]];

// JavaScript usa como estándar el formato de fecha ISO (YYYY-MM-DD)
// const diaPedido = new Date('2019-01-04');
// Leyendo un poco tu comentario con más atención veo que la fecha de pedido
// es la fecha actual, por lo tanto edito para que la respuesta se ajuste a tu pregunta

const diaPedido = new Date(Date.now());
// Construimos la fecha usando como parámetro el valor devuelto por Date.now().

// La siguiente función recibe como parámetros:
// diaPedido: Es el día inicial, (cuando se recibe un pedido), tipo: Date
// diasPactados: Es la cantidad de días laborales que han sido pactados para entrega, tipo: Number
// festivos: Es el Array que hemos inicializado anteriormente y contiene los días festivos del año, tipo: Array
//      Se espera que los días festivos sean fijos de año en año, pero pudieran modificarse.
//      Así que sólo hay que asegurarse de pasar el array de festivos mas actualizado a la función.

function calculaEntrega(diaPedido, diasPactados, festivos) {
    // diaPropuesto: almacena el mismo valor de diaPedido, en caso que diasPactados = 0, la función 
    // devolverá el valor de diaPedido (para mi tiene lógica)
    let diaPropuesto = new Date(diaPedido.getFullYear(), diaPedido.getMonth(), diaPedido.getDate());

    // iniciamos un contador en 1 para calcular la fecha de diaPropuesto.
    let i = 1;
    
    // El siguiente bucle se ejecutará hasta que se consuman los diasPactados
    while (diasPactados > 0 ) {
        // En cada iteración asumimos que el día no es festivo
        let festivo = false;
        // incrementamos en 1 el diaPropuesto para efectuar las verificaciones
        diaPropuesto = new Date(diaPedido.getFullYear(), diaPedido.getMonth(), diaPedido.getDate() + i);
        // Nótese que usamos formato ISO y solo incrementamos el día, dejando el mes y el año iguales
        // Alguien preguntará: ¿Y que pasa si la fecha es, digamos, 31 de Enero y le aumentamos 1 día?
        // Pues la respuesta lógica es que daría 32 de Enero, lo cual no es una fecha válida.
        // Sin embargo, JavaScript es un poco mas atento que nosotros y simplemente realiza la aritmética
        // necesaria para convertir el 32 de Enero en 01 de Febrero, y así nos salva el pellejo.
        // Véase bien que usamos los métodos getFullYear(), getMonth() y getDate().
        // Esto funciona siempre y cuando hagamos la construcción del objeto Date de esta manera.
        // Ya irá alguno de avispado y pondrá: fecha = new Date('2019-01-32'); lo cual le dará 'fecha inválida'
        // Alguien un poco mas versado puede aclarar este asunto, pero no es el objetivo en este momento.

        if (diaPropuesto.getDay() > 0 && diaPropuesto.getDay() < 6) {
            // Aquí hemos usado el método getDay() del objeto Date, este método devuelve un valor entero entre 0 y 6,
            // donde 0: Domingo, 1: Lunes, ... , 6: Sabado.
            // Los días laborables van del 1 al 5 (ambos inclusive)
            
            // Si el día es laborable debemos entonces verificar si es festivo
            
            // Aquí es importante que entendamos lo siguiente:
            //  * Por cada iteración debemos obtener el mes en el que estamos comprobando el festivo
            //  * Vamos a comparar el día propuesto con el Array de festivos, usando el mes correspondiente

            let m = diaPropuesto.getMonth();
            let dia = diaPropuesto.getDate();

            // Felizmente para nosotros el método getMonth() devuelve un entero entre 0 y 11, que se
            // corresponde con cada mes del año, y digo felizmente, porque los índices de nuestro Array
            // van de 0 a 11 también.

            for (let d in festivos[m]) {
                if (dia === festivos[m][d]) {
                    festivo = true;
                    //Aquí no hay mucho que aclarar, si es festivo ya no sigo comprobando el resto del mes.
                    break;
                }
            } // Fin bucle for

            if (!festivo) {
                // Si las condiciones son: Laborable y No Festivo, descuento el diaPactado.
                diasPactados--;
            }
        }

        // Por último, debemos incrementar el número de días que sumaremos al diaPropuesto
        // en cada iteración
        i++;
    } // Fin de bucle while

    // Devolvemos el resultado
    return diaPropuesto;

} // Fin función



// Finalmente asignamos nuestra variable diaEntrega, la cual contendra un Objeto Date valido indicando
// la fecha en que el pedido sera entregado.

const diaEntrega = calculaEntrega(diaPedido, 10, festivos);

console.log(`Dia de pedido: ${diaPedido.toString()}`);
console.log(`Dia de entrega calculado: ${diaEntrega.toString()}`);
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea satisfactoria.

**Nota: Los festivos son ficticios.**

Answer (score 0):

la verdad que no vi donde. soy nuevo consultando por aqui bueno lo siguiente del codigo es uno de prueba que tengo que su funcion es dado la fecha actual al hacer un pedido hacer una entrega en 10 dias o x cantidad de dias pero que no cuente los fines de semana y los dia no laborables como feriados festivos y dar el dia exacto como por ejemplo hoy viernes/21/12/2018 se hace un pedido de 5 dias comienza a contar de desde el lunes/24/12/2018 sin contar sabado y domingo y el martes 25/12/2018  porq es dia feriado y sigue contando miercoles/26/12/2018 asi hasta los 5 dias que seria el sabado/29 y domingo/30 no se cuentan porq es fin de semana y el lunes31/12/2018 que seria los 5 dias estimado de la entraga del pedido

Comment: Saludos, Jesús, este espacio es para respuestas. Si necesitas editar tu pregunta, debes dar click en la palabra "editar" que se encuentra debajo de tu pregunta *(o haz click [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/132728))*. Saludos.