# Agregar 3 dias habiles a fecha sin contar festivos

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una automatización y estoy atascado en una función de Javascript, la función debe hacer lo siguiente:

Tomar la fecha de hoy, sumar 2 días sin contar sábado, domingo y festivos luego devolver la fecha.
Buscando y probando logre conseguir que la función devuelva la suma de los días sin contar sábados y domingos, pero no he logrado conseguir que no tome los dias festivos.

```
function pad2(n) { // return 2-character string
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}

function diasHabiles(){
    var d = new Date();
i=0;
while (i<2) {
  d.setTime(d.getTime()+24*60*60*1000);
  if (d.getDay() != 6 && d.getDay() !== 0)
    i++;
}
return pad2(d.getDate()) + "/" +
        pad2(d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
        d.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: En tu código estás usando el método `Date.getDay()`, y con eso te sacas de encima los días Sábado y Domingo. Lo que no queda claro, y no está definido en tu código, es qué criterio es el que usas para determinar si un día es festivo.

Comment: Relacionado: [*calcular fecha de entrega solo tomando en cuenta los días laborables en javascript*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225102/calcular-fecha-de-entrega-solo-tomando-en-cuenta-los-dias-laborables-en-javascri/227144#227144)

Comment: Lo de calcular los días festivos no tengo idea como hacerlo, he intentado con un array guardando los días de cada mes que son festivos pero no me funciona... Acabo de ver el enlace relacionado... intentare implementar eso. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Mmmmmm bueno te pondré un ejemplo distinto del [enlace que pusieron](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225102/calcular-fecha-de-entrega-solo-tomando-en-cuenta-los-dias-laborables-en-javascri/227144#227144) donde lo que hago es simplemente adicionar los dias y meses de los festivos en un *Ärray* y cuando se le suma los dias verifica si es festivo o fin de semana entonces le suma un dia  y repite esto según cuantos dias quieras adicionar, dejaré el código comentado para que comprendas lo que estoy haciendo:

```
var nuevaFecha = getSinFestivosNiFinDeSemana('2019-12-24', 7);
console.log('Nueva fecha: ' + nuevaFecha);

function getSinFestivosNiFinDeSemana(fecha, diasAdd) {
    var arrFecha = fecha.split('-');
    var fecha = new Date(arrFecha[0], arrFecha[1] - 1, arrFecha[2]);
    var festivos = [ // Agregamos los festivos (dia, mes)
        [25, 12],
        [1, 1]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < diasAdd; i++) {
        var diaInvalido = false;
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 1); // Sumamos de dia en dia
        for (var j = 0; j < festivos.length; j++) { // Verificamos si el dia + 1 es festivo
            var mesDia = festivos[j];
            if (fecha.getMonth() + 1 == mesDia[1] && fecha.getDate() == mesDia[0]) {
                console.log(fecha.getDate() + ' es dia festivo (Sumamos un dia)');
                diaInvalido = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (fecha.getDay() == 0 || fecha.getDay() == 6) { // Verificamos si es sábado o domingo
            console.log(fecha.getDate() + ' es sábado o domingo (Sumamos un dia)');
            diaInvalido = true;
        }
        if (diaInvalido)
            diasAdd++; // Si es fin de semana o festivo le sumamos un dia
    }
    return fecha.getFullYear() + '-' + (fecha.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + fecha.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
}
```

Salida:

> ```
> 25 es dia festivo (Sumamos un dia)
> 28 es sábado o domingo (Sumamos un dia)
> 29 es sábado o domingo (Sumamos un dia)
> 1 es dia festivo (Sumamos un dia)
> 4 es sábado o domingo (Sumamos un dia)
> 5 es sábado o domingo (Sumamos un dia)
> Nueva fecha: 2020-01-06
> ```

Bueno en éste caso el **Date** se encuentra en *2019-12-24* fecha en la que comienza y le suma **7 dias** para mi ejemplo la salida de la nueva fecha como vez es *2020-01-06*, puse en consola los dias que no toma en cuenta.

Espero el ejemplo te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Hola, creo que estoy haciendo algo mal pero cuando intento probar la funcion me da el siguiente error: JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on line 8... alguna idea de que hago mal...

Comment: Se me ocurre que la fecha que estas enviando se encuentre vacia por alguna razón, podrias poner un `console.log(fecha)` antes de la línea donde se encuentra el `split` para verificar que el valor sea una cadena de la fecha en formato *YYYY-MM-DD*

Comment: Hola, reinicie mi pc y ahora si me funciona, de igual forma tengo una duda ¿como hago que en: var nuevaFecha = getSinFestivosNiFinDeSemana('2019-12-24', 7);
 tome la fecha del día y no una definida?

Comment: Puedes hacer eso con `var fecha = new Date()` pero luego tendras que hacer uso de sus respectivos `get` para obtener el dia, mes y año. Puedes hecharle un ojo a [éste enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date). ;)